Is there a way to define class methods for ACF `renderCallback` in block.json?
I have a custom Gutenberg block defined with the following block.json:
{
    "name": "my-blocks/contact",
    "title": "Contact",
    "category": "my-blocks",
    "acf": {
        "mode": "edit",
        "renderCallback": "block_render_callback"
    }
}

The block is registered using register_block_type('path/to/block.json')
The above works fine and the block is rendering when the render callback is set to my global function block_render_callback.
I am trying to figure out a way to define the renderCallback as a class method. Is there a way to do it?
I tried the following:
{
    "name": "my-blocks/contact",
    "title": "Contact",
    "category": "my-blocks",
    "acf": {
        "mode": "edit",
        "renderCallback": "ACFCompatibility::render"
    }
}

The block is not rendering at all.
The following doesn't work either:
{
    "name": "my-blocks/contact",
    "title": "Contact",
    "category": "my-blocks",
    "acf": {
        "mode": "edit",
        "renderCallback": "\\ACFCompatibility\\render"
    }
}


What got it working for me was to add the plugin's namespace before the class name and also to include the file containing the class first.
So before your block.json gets evaluated, you'd do your include/require on the class file, then inside the json it'd be:
"renderCallback": "YourNamespace\\ACFCompatibility::render"


In my case the method registering blocks lives in the same class ACFCompatibility. Any idea how to do it in my case? I tried including the namespace like so but no luck: MyNameSpace\\ACFCompatibility::render. I also tried this self::render.

I think the array structure for static callables would go like "ACF compatibility::class, render"


with a possibility that you need to change the word "class" to the word "self" as I'm really not sure how the block handles it. "ACF compatibility::self, render". Also is your method public?


I did not manage to get it working but thank you for your suggestions. For now I will just keep the render function globally, which is not a big issue.
